# executing an oracle package function

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Hi i have an oracle function already present in the database which i have to use.
if i call the function as below it works fine

```
select PKG_Util.employeedetails('12345') from dual;
```

But if i try to pass in multiple identifiers, this statement doesnt execute

```
select PKG_Util.employeedetails(select id from dbo.emp_details) from dual;
```

i understand that dual would output only one row.

But is there any other way i can pass multiple rows on emp id's to execute the function-package and get the output.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select PKG_Util.employeedetails(id) from dbo.emp_details;
```